# Shortcut to open a file with a different program

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, file-association

Is it possible to open a file in Windows 7 or later with a combination of a keyboard key and double click (say control+double click) with a diffferent program than the assosiated one?
I wish to open video files with control and double click with BSplayer and with normal double click with PotPlayer.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you can find some third party tool to enable custom key shortcuts this is not possible in native Windows.

The other alternative that is native is right click > Open With > ...Whatever application...